Conditionally rendering a lazy-loaded component only after the parent node is attached results in an infinite loop
React version: 18.3.1
Steps To Reproduce
Create a component that renders the children inside a , but only after it has obtained reference to that div (via putting the div node into a state)
Pass a lazy loaded component as children
So basically something like:
import { Suspense, lazy, useState } from 'react';

const LazyLoadedComponent = lazy(
  () =>
    new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(
        () =>
          resolve({
            default: () => <div>Lazy loaded component</div>,
          }),
        500,
      );
    }),
);

const RenderAfterMount = (props) => {
  const [node, setNode] = useState(null);

  return <div ref={setNode}>{node && props.children}</div>;
};

export const App = () => (
  <Suspense>
    <RenderAfterMount>
      <LazyLoadedComponent />
    </RenderAfterMount>
  </Suspense>
);

Link to code example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-uqnpwm?file=src%2FApp.jsx
The current behavior
Runtime error due to an infinite loop.
The expected behavior
The lazy loaded component is rendered.

You can can capture the reference of the node using const ref = useRef() but I'm not understanding your use case here the content inside of Suspense is considered as a single unit so even if one component will take time all the  other will be rendered once the one taking time resolves, in short there is no need for you to add RenderAfterMount it will just work fine

import { Suspense, lazy, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import './styles.css';

const LazyLoadedComponent = lazy(
  () =>
    new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(
        () =>
          resolve({
            default: () => (
              <div style={{ background: 'green' }}>Lazy loaded component</div>
            ),
          }),
        5000
      );
    })
);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Suspense>
        <SomeRandomComponent/>
          <LazyLoadedComponent />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}

const SomeRandomComponent = (props) => {
  return <div>rendering</div>
};



in this example both the text rendering and the actual lazy loaded component will be rendered after 5 seconds

The proper hook to use in this case is useRef. In your example the setNode function is, well, setting the state (value) for the node constant during the rendering; that process re-renders the component thus generating the infinite loop.
The following code uses useRef hook and validates that the ref is set (node.current) before rendering the children.
import { Suspense, lazy, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import './styles.css';

const LazyLoadedComponent = lazy(
  () =>
    new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(
        () =>
          resolve({
            default: () => (
              <div style={{ background: 'green' }}>Lazy loaded component</div>
            ),
          }),
        500
      );
    })
);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Suspense>
        <RenderAfterMount>
          <LazyLoadedComponent />
        </RenderAfterMount>
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}

const RenderAfterMount = (props) => {
  const node = useRef(null);

  return <div ref={node}>{node?.current && props.children}</div>;
};

Hope this helps you understand and solve the problem.

Thank you for the suggestion to use useRef instead of setting state with useState. However, in my specific use case, I need to determine when the parent element has been fully attached to the DOM. This is because I need the parent (a dialog element) to first render without any content, allowing it to take focus, and then immediately render its children after attachment. The children might have autofocus set, which needs to be respected once the dialog is in focus.
Do you have any advice on how I can achieve this behavior?

Hi @SurenPoghosyan I think the useRef approach should still work since node.current will not evaluate to true until the ref is set. Another option you can try is to create another component that uses setTimeout set a state variable to true and use that as a validation to display the children. This approach may work but is a different task than the one you were asking for initially.
